# WPF Border Layout with a pointer on top corner

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can we design a border with a pointer on any of its corners, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do a border with some background color and a pointer on its corner (say on top left) using XAML?

The screenshot is from the `Books.Show` sample project on MSDN resources.

Comment: At first, you need to decide with the control. Usually it's `ToolTip` or `Popup`. Then you create a template for it and you use this control with this template. Example [link](http://stevenhollidge.blogspot.ru/2012/04/custom-tooltip-and-popup.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like

```
<StackPanel>
    <Path Data="M0,0 L5,5 L0,5" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Fill="Red" 
          Stretch="Fill" 
          Height="20" 
          Width="20"             
          Margin="0,0,0,-2"></Path>
    <Border Height="50" Background="Red" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: this is exaclty what i am looking for